# Difference between array sorting

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I learned two ways of sorting an array:

Bubble sorting:

```
import java.io.*;
class bubbles
{
    int ctr;
    int ctr1;
    int a[]= new int[5];
    int pos;
    int temp;
    int max;
    public void method () throws IOException
    {
        int max=0;
        BufferedReader obj= new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
        System.out.println ("Enter five numbers");
        for (ctr=0; ctr<5; ctr++)
        {
            a[ctr]= Integer.parseInt (obj.readLine ());
        }

        for (ctr=0; ctr<5; ctr++)
        {
            for (ctr1=1; ctr1<4; ctr1++)
            {
                if (a[ctr1]>a[ctr1+1])
                {
                    temp=a[ctr1];
                    a[ctr1]=a[ctr1+1];
                    a[ctr1+1]=temp;
                }
            }
        }
        for (ctr=0; ctr<5; ctr++)
        {
            System.out.print (a[ctr1] +" ");
        }
    }
}
```

And selection sorting:

```
import java.io.*;
class selectionprocess
{
    int ctr;
    int ctr1;
    int a[]= new int[5];
    int pos;
    int temp;
    int max;
    public void method () throws IOException
    {
        int max=0;
        BufferedReader obj= new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
        System.out.println ("Enter five numbers");
        for (ctr=0; ctr<5; ctr++)
        {
            a[ctr]= Integer.parseInt (obj.readLine ());
        }

        for (ctr=0; ctr<5; ctr++)
        {
            max=a[ctr];
            pos=ctr;
            for (ctr1=ctr+1; ctr1<5; ctr1++)
            {
                if (a[ctr1]>max)
                {
                    max=a[ctr1];
                    pos=ctr1;
                }
            }
            temp=a[pos];
            a[pos]=a[ctr];
            a[ctr]=temp;
        }
        for (ctr=0; ctr<5; ctr++)
        {
            System.out.print (a[ctr] +" ");
        }
    }
}
```

**Logically speaking, what is the difference between these two methods? What are their uses and which one is faster and more efficient?**

Comment: Have you seen the algorithm on wikipedia? That will certainly make you understand how they are different.

Comment: Both are pretty rubbish, they run in `O(n^2)` time. Bubble sort is never used in real programs (or at least shouldn't be). Selection sort is sometimes used due to lower constant factors making it faster for very small arrays. The common types of sort are [Merge Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) and [Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) which run the the best possible time - `O(n lg n)` (on average technically). The Java JDK uses [Timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) internally.

Comment: there are even more sorting algorithms (QuickSort, MergeSort, ...)
A nice comparison can be found here: http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/

Comment: However, my question is both better written and shows code compared to the old one. The answers are also better.

Comment: @VedantChandra false and false. Well, maybe true on the "more code" but I don't think anyone here needs to see an implementation to understand what a bubble sort is.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I think that's incorrect, there's a lot of beginners on this site and it's always better to have enough information in a question so that pretty much any skill-leveled person can understand it. Remember, this website is also a learning resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Selection Sort**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort):

Selection sort is to repetitively pick up the smallest element and put it into the right position:

Find the smallest element, and put it to the first position.
Find the next smallest element, and put it to the second position.
Repeat until all elements are in the right positions.

complexity  **О(n^2)**

[**Bubble Sort**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort):

Bubble sort repetitively compares adjacent pairs of elements and swaps if necessary.

Scan the array, swapping adjacent pair of elements if they are not in relative order. This bubbles up the largest element to the end.
Scan the array again, bubbling up the second largest element.
Repeat until all elements are in order.

complexity  **О(n^2)**

(best-case) is **O(n)**

Answer (score 0):

Selection Sort is Faster than bubble sort.
Both of them have:

1. **Worst case time complexity**: O(n<sup>2</sup>)
2. **Number of comparisons**     : O(n<sup>2</sup>)
3. **Best case time complexity** :

   - Bubble sort:O(n)
   - Selection sort:O(n<sup>2</sup>)
4. **Average case time complexity** :

   - Bubble sort: O(n<sup>2</sup>)
   - Selection sort: O(n<sup>2</sup>)

Comment: This statement is not true _Selection Sort is Faster than bubble sort_. As you point out yourself bubble sort is `O(n)` on sorted data but selection sort is `O(n^2)`. You can say it is _generally_ faster, or _on average_ faster.

Answer (score 0):

Both sorts are quadratic in time, so they should be used only for small arrays. Bubble sort is trivial to code in any language and depending on how you do the compare, it is usually stable (does not exchange two values when equal.) Selection sort is maybe a little faster, but is not stable. Stability comes into play when, for example, you have a two dimensional array that you want to sort first by one column, then the other column. When the second sort is done and two values are equal, the first column will no longer be sorted. There are many examples and demonstrations on the Internet.